# Java: Hex-String split by Hex-Byte with regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to Split a HEX-String in Java using split(), regex or any other convenient method.
What I want to do is to split it at a special Byte in HEX.

Example:

```
String hex = "1234567E1237E6787E4321";
String del = "7E"; // ~
hex.split( ????? );
```

Result should be:

```
123456
1237E678
4321
```

If I use **hex.split( del );** I get:

```
123456
123
678
4321
```

Comment: Why `1237E678` shouldn't be split on `7E`? What rationale *you* are using to make that decision?

Comment: because it splits also at halfbytes, which is not intended

Comment: Is `hex.split("(?<=\\G([a-fA-F0-9]{2}){0,100000000})" + del)` considered simple/convenient ?

Comment: If you write a private method which does this without using regex, it will be just as efficient, if not more so.  And it’s not a lot of code; just a List and a short loop.

Comment: Great, that works!!